# Where can I find a simple tutorial on setting up twitter/google and open id user login forms for my PHP web app?

Tags: php

I have tried official Google, Twitter and Open ID tutorials and cannot get a universal login system to work for my web app.

Help please

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice [Open ID tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3581) on Zend's Devzone. That should give you some hints how to implement it.